# Laravel change validation language

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I change the validator language messages. For example if I want to change the 'required' text 'The kilometerszakelijk field is required.' to something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All language specific content is stored in your **resources/lang//** folder. One of the files you'll find in this folder is **validation.php** that holds validation messages for given language, so if you want to change the translations, you'll need to edit that file.

Depending on the language that is used by the application, messages will be read from different folders in **resources/lang/**. You can set language/locale using

```
App::setLocale('en');
```

You can also set fallback locale (that is used when there are no translations for current language) by setting it in your **config/app.php** file, e.g.:

```
'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

See more details in the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/localization

Comment: You could simply download the language you need right [here](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang)

Answer (score 3):

Create a folder named like your language code in

```
resources/lang
```

then create a file in this folder called `validation.php` and in there, write something like

```
return [

    'required'    => 'Das Feld :attribute ist ein Pflichtfeld.',

]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the default messages, you can adjust the translations in `resources/lang/<language>/validation.php`.

You can also pass [entirely custom messages](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-error-messages) to the validator.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel-lang**

In this repository, you can find the lang files for the framework PHP, Laravel 4&5.

you can see [here](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang) for use that.

Answer (score 0):

To configure the default language in Laravel 10x, navigate to the config/app.php file and locate the following line:

```
 'locale' => 'ru'
```

Additionally, you can dynamically switch the active language in PHP using the following code snippet:

```
App::setLocale('ru');
```

To display validation messages in the active language, you need to publish the lang directory in your project by executing php artisan lang:publish. This command will generate the lang/en directory containing files such as auth.php, validation.php, and others.

Next, create a directory for your desired language within the lang/ directory and create the necessary files. For example:

```
lang/
    en/
     ...
    ru/
      auth.php
      pagination.php
      passwords.php
      validation.php
```

In the validation.php file, define your validation rules as follows:

```
{
   'regex' => 'The :attribute field format is invalid.',
   'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
}
```

This setup will ensure that validation messages are displayed in the specified language.